# Default value in daynimic fitering

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list-filter

I am using SharePoint online moden page. I have two libraries as below

1. Countries : have list of countries
2. Related Documents library: this library has lookup of Countries as metadata

On Home page I have added Countires webpart as Gallery view and added documents webpart as well. I used Dynamic filtering to filter related documents when someone clicks on country button.

[image]

[image]

Now there is requirment that whenever page is loaded, by default China should be selected in list of countries button. like in screenshot Aurstria is selected.
I am not sure how to achieve this as I am new to SharePoint online. Please guide me.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to select a default list/library item on page load using SharePoint default web parts.